# Identical hashes for a guid in both C# and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, hash, guid

I have a problem where I need to be able to generate identical uniformly distributed numeric hashs for a GUID in both javascript and C#. I guess that would prevent me from using `Guid.GetHashCode()` in C#, since I can't reproduce the behavior in JS without reverse engineering the C#.

Is there a *fast* way to produce hashes from guids/strings in JS? Are all digits of the string uniformly distributed in a .NET generated GUID? Should I just cast/convert the trailing chars into an int?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bytes are apparently not evenly distributed.

I put together some code to sample the .NET Guids and plot the distribution:

First of all the test code, this creates one million Guids and counts the number of different values for each byte in the byte array. It outputs it all into a matrix that I plot in [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/).

```
int[,] counter = new int[16, 256];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    var g = Guid.NewGuid();
    var bytes = g.ToByteArray();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 16; idx++)
    {
        counter[idx, bytes[idx]]++;
    }
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("x = [");
for (int idx = 0; idx < 16; idx++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
    {
        sb.Append(counter[idx, b]);
        if (idx != 255)
        {
            sb.Append(" ");
        }
    }
    if (idx != 15)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(";");
    }
}
sb.AppendLine("]");

File.WriteAllText("plot.sce", sb.ToString());
```

Here are the distributions, the graphs plot the number of each distinct value for each of the positions in the byte array:

The value distribution for the positions 0-6 in the byte array: 
[image: The value distribution for the positions 0-6 in the byte array]
The value distribution for the position 7 in the byte array:
[image: The value distribution for the position 7 in the byte array]
The value distribution for the position 8 in the byte array:
[image: The value distribution for the position 8 in the byte array]
The value distribution for the positions 9-15 in the byte array:
[image: The value distribution for the positions 9-15 in the byte array]

For byte positions 0-6 and 9-15 the distribution of values seems to be even, but for byte position 7 and 8 the distribution is fairly limited.

That is, for the guid (with the beginning of the byte positions below, note strange ordering)

```
{1369ea05-b9f9-408b-ac7c-7ebd0f35d562}
                         1 1 1 1 1 1
 3 2 1 0  5 4  7 6  8 9  0 1 2 3 4 5
```

The position 7 can take the values from 64 (0x40) to 79 (0x4F).
The position 8 can take the values from 128 (0x80) to 191 (0xBF).
The rest of the bytes are evenly distributed.

**Note:** The tests was run on .NET4 on a 32 bit Windows 7 machine.

**Lesson:** don't assume stuff, test.

**Answer:** To use the .NET Guids for calculating your load balancing, you can use any part except the positions marked 7 and 8 in the Guid above.

**Question:** Does anybody know WHY the distribution is not evenly spread?

Comment: Wow, Albin. You earned that! Thank you very much. BTW: The comment on this answer provides a clue as to why the bits are not uniform in pos 7 & 8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript/105074#105074. Perhaps some of the bits provide details about the generation method/provenance of the GUID?

Comment: Ah, some versioning information and a markers for some algorithmic choices.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a web service to generate the hash value on the server side, use whatever language you want. on client side, a simple web service call will do the trick.

Comment: I was after something fast - I need to avoid a round-trip to the server, or between server machines. It's to allow a kind of load balancing, that doesn't require hardware and that will allow my Ajax app to fail over gracefully without having to wait.

Comment: what's the purpose of calculating the guid hash? Do you want to use it for load balancing?

Comment: I need it to be able to identify (from anywhere in the server side or client side) a specific subset of the IIS servers to pass cache data to in readiness for an incoming request from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Reflector says the .NET Guid.GetHashCode() is implemented like this

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return ((this._a ^ ((this._b << 0x10) | ((ushort) this._c))) ^ ((this._f << 0x18) | this._k));
}
```

_a, _b, _c and _f is defined in the constructor taking a byte[16] array

```
public Guid(byte[] b)
{
    if (b == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
    }
    if (b.Length != 0x10)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_GuidArrayCtor", new object[] { "16" }));
    }
    this._a = (((b[3] << 0x18) | (b[2] << 0x10)) | (b[1] << 8)) | b[0];
    this._b = (short) ((b[5] << 8) | b[4]);
    this._c = (short) ((b[7] << 8) | b[6]);
    this._d = b[8];
    this._e = b[9];
    this._f = b[10];
    this._g = b[11];
    this._h = b[12];
    this._i = b[13];
    this._j = b[14];
    this._k = b[15];
}
```

Comment: Is there a non-string based representation for GUIDs in JS? I suspect that conversion of the string (that I'd be receiving) into a byte array, and from there into a GUID in order to generate the int would be wasteful if there was a more direct way to create a good hash from a string representation.

Comment: To just create an index for load balancing this seems to be overkill. The conversion to the bytes is done simply by grouping the letters 2 by 2 and parse them as a hex value. I have done some tests with the distribution if the digits and it looks like some bytes are more common than other, but I have to look into more detail about where the differences are before I can post anything about that.